# Converting XML Document to a DOM4J doc to extract value of specific nodes

Tags: java, xml, string, nodes, dom4j

I have an XML document with various nodes. I need to put a set of nodes into a string.
Example:

```
<root>
<....many tags>
<TIFFs>
<TIFF>.......blah blah...</TIFF>
<TIFF>.......blah blah...</TIFF>
<TIFF>.......blah blah...</TIFF>
<TIFF>.......blah blah...</TIFF>
<TIFF>.......blah blah...</TIFF>
</TIFFs>
<other tags>
</root>
```

I am trying to have all the data from the TIFFs node and all child nodes, namely TIFF in a string. I have tried various things, I came to know that it is possbile in Java with Dom4J. I would appreciate any suggestions on that. I had done it in a different way using W3C nodes, but it does not work correctly everytime.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
List nodeList = document.selectNodes( "//root/tiffs/tiff" );
for(Node node : nodeList) { 
   System.out.println("tiff:" + node.getText();
}
```

Comment: what is document? i.e what is the data type of document? thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: when I try it in Eclipse, this is what happens: List nodeList = document.selectNodes( "//root/tiffs/tiff" ); for(Node node : nodeList) { System.out.println("tiff:" + node.getTextContent(); } It changes getText to getTextContent, and it gives an error with document saying document cannot be resolved, since I dont know what type to declare it as. I though it should be element or org.dom4j.Element or w3c? and then for the for loop, it underlines nodeList and says "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"... I appreciate your help.

Comment: document shoud be of type org.dom4j.Document